# Is "Have Fun!" in Imperative Mood?

Tags: imperatives, mood

Also, what about the following:

1. Be safe.
2. Think different.
3. Drive safely.

My guess is that these are, but just confirming in case there is a catch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. All these sentences are definitely in Imperative Mood. But don't draw any semantic conclusions from the rather solemn sound of the grammatical term.